# Call to a member function validate() on array

Tags: php, laravel

I need your help for a project Im doing at the moment.
I am using Laravel for programming and Im getting this error: 'Call to a member function validate() on array'

This is my store method

```
public function store()
    {
        $data = $this->check();

        switch ($data) {
            case (0):
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Dieses Produkt ist nicht vorhanden');
            case (1):
                return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Das Produkt mit dieser Liefer-Nummer ist bereits vorhanden');
            default:
                Product::create($data)->save();

                return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

this is the check method

```
public function check()
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach(Validation::all() as $valid)
        {
            $validation[$i] = [
                'id' => $valid->id,
                'Produkt' => $valid->Produkt,
                'PHmax' => $valid->PHmax,
                'PHmin' => $valid->PHmin,
                'Wassermax' => $valid->Wassermax,
                'Wassermin' => $valid->Wassermin,
                'Dichtemax' => $valid->Dichtemax,
                'Dichtemin' => $valid->Dichtemin,
            ];
            $i = $i + 1;
        }
        $data = [
            'LieferNr' => request()->LieferNr,
            'Produkt' => request()->Produkt,
            'PH' => request()->PH,
            'Wasser' => request()->Wasser,
            'Dichte' => request()->Dichte,
            'Bearbeiter' => request()->Bearbeiter,
        ];
        $bigdata = Product::all();
        foreach(Validation::all() as $valid){
            foreach($bigdata as $bigdata){
                if($data['LieferNr'] == $bigdata->LieferNr){
                    return 1;
                }
            }

            if(in_array($data['Produkt'], $validation[0]) || in_array($data['Produkt'], $validation[1] ))
            {
                $PHmax = $valid->PHmax;
                $PHmin = $valid->PHmin;
                $Wassermax = $valid->Wassermax;
                $Wassermin = $valid->Wassermin;
                $Dichtemax = $valid->Dichtemax;
                $Dichtemin = $valid->Dichtemin;

                return $data->validate([
                    'LieferNr' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:5'],
                    'Produkt' => ['required'],
                    'PH' => ['required', 'numeric', "min:$PHmin", "max:$PHmax"],
                    'Wasser' => "required|numeric|min:$Wassermin|max:$Wassermax",
                    'Dichte' => "required|numeric|min:$Dichtemin|max:$Dichtemax",
                    'Bearbeiter' => ['required'],
                ]);
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

The error occurs when i do $data->validate(...)
I am quite new to Laravel and i would be happy if you can help me :)

Comment: What is this code meant to be doing? It seems very needlessly complicated. Also, in modern code validation is generally done by FormRequest; controller validation is usually only seen in old code.

Comment: `foreach($bigdata as $bigdata)` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem
It is because you are calling validate on array `$data`

```
return $data->validate([
                    'LieferNr' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:5'],
                    'Produkt' => ['required'],
                    'PH' => ['required', 'numeric', "min:$PHmin", "max:$PHmax"],
                    'Wasser' => "required|numeric|min:$Wassermin|max:$Wassermax",
                    'Dichte' => "required|numeric|min:$Dichtemin|max:$Dichtemax",
                    'Bearbeiter' => ['required'],
                ]);
```

Instead, do following

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
                    'LieferNr' => ['required', 'min:5', 'max:5'],
                    'Produkt' => ['required'],
                    'PH' => ['required', 'numeric', "min:$PHmin", "max:$PHmax"],
                    'Wasser' => "required|numeric|min:$Wassermin|max:$Wassermax",
                    'Dichte' => "required|numeric|min:$Dichtemin|max:$Dichtemax",
                    'Bearbeiter' => ['required'],
                ]);

if($validator->fails()){
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I changed the check function and now i get another error: 'Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create(): Argument #1 ($attributes) must be of type array' How can I fix this problem?

Comment: dd($data) after  $data = $this->check();

Comment: ok i got it replace `return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();`  with `return 0;`

Comment: ```Illuminate\Validation\Validator {#276 ▼
  #translator: Illuminate\Translation\Translator {#1219 ▶}
  #container: Illuminate\Foundation\Application {#3 ▶}
  #presenceVerifier: Illuminate\Validation\DatabasePresenceVerifier {#1217 ▶}
  #failedRules: []
  #excludeAttributes: []
  #messages: null
  #data: array:6 [▼
    "LieferNr" => "13133"
    "Produkt" => "Warm"
    "PH" => "5"
    "Wasser" => "9"
    "Dichte" => "1.4"
    "Bearbeiter" => "asd"
  ]```

Comment: I dont think the Validator is failing. I think the Problem is, that the actual Data is in Illuminate\Validation\Validator->data->[.....] and that the method cant get access to the data

Comment: Now its working. I changed the return part ```if($validator->fails()){
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return $data;
                }```